# BCS, field captions/title localizations

Tags: bcs

We've developed BCS appllication and now have no ideas about how to localize fields titles in BCS model. Where some xml tags in BCS model definition, but it did not work in our practise.

Does anybody have working samples/experience with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

see [Step 7 (Optional): Localize the BDC Model File (Metadata.bdcm)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742823.aspx) and [Localize Column Titles in BDC](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointbdc/thread/86f6c2ba-7363-4709-8733-2d0dda72e34c)

IMO it should be a lot easier than that...

Comment: Yes, exactly.
We did it but it didn't work. Ok, I'll try to review our code and find what we've done wrong.